# Cannot link to a running container started by docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am setting up my local development environment with docker containers.  The docker-compose.yml is like following

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo:3
  mq:
    image: rabbitmq:3
  api:
    build: .
    image: my_app/api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db
      - mq
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

It starts without error.
And docker lists 3 running containers

```
docker-compose up -d
docker ps

e90e5a8b5d33        my_app/api    "/usr/local/bin/node "   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp               my_app_api_1
42bfcd971b16        mongo:3       "/entrypoint.sh mongo"   27017/tcp                            my_app_db_1
a0685a816c47        rabbitmq:3    "/docker-entrypoint.s"   4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 25672/tcp   my_app_mq_1
```

However when I try to link to those running containers from another container

```
docker run --link my_app_mq_1:mq --link my_app_db_1:db -it worker
```

I get error

```
 docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to /my_app_mq_1, as it does not belong to the default network.
```

I have also tried

```
 docker run --link my_app_mq_1:mq --link my_app_db_1:db -it --net default worker
```

Same error.

So how can I link to a running container started by docker-compose?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Ok, found the answer to it. In case anyone else comes across the same problem, just do

```
docker network ls
```

This command lists all the docker networks. docker-compose will create a new network when you run docker-compose up. In my case, the network is named as myapp_default.

> Note: Your app’s network is given a name based on the “project name”, which is based on the name of the directory it lives in. You can override the project name with either the --project-name flag or the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable. [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

So the correct way to link to those containers is

```
docker run --link my_app_mq_1:mq --link my_app_db_1:db -it --net myapp_default worker
```

Comment: For those who didn't notice you have to put the `--net` before the command. I encountered this problem when trying to run the official redis docker image.

Comment: I had to use the --network flag, instead of the --net. Use it at the start of the run command. I hope this helps. Reference is available here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings.

Answer (score 17):

my command to run links

```
docker run --network=YOUR_NETWORK --link SERVICE -t -i app command
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use service definition version 2 and more, `docker-compose` creates user-defined network. Name resolution in a user-defined network works via Docker embedded DNS server. Here's related quote from [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/):

> The Docker embedded DNS server enables name resolution for containers connected to a given [user-defined] network. This means that any connected container can ping another container on the same network by its container name.

Containers are also available by network aliases that `docker-compose` creates. It can be verified by command like:

```
docker inspect \
  -f '{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks.myapp_default.Aliases}}' my_app_db_1
```

It prints `["db","$CONTAINER_ID"]`.

Providing links with `--link` will not have any effect in case of existing user-defined network. You can make sure and look at `/etc/hosts`, which will not have the corresponding lines.

Thus the following command is sufficient:

```
docker run -it --net myapp_default worker
```