# Console PHP script runs differently when executes through docker exec or through PhpStorm

Tags: php, docker, pdo, phpstorm

I'm trying to run console run Doctrine 2's console script through the PhpStorm. Docker is set up as Deploy server.

If I run this:

`$ docker exec container_name /var/www/vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create`

it prints:

> No Metadata Classes to process.

But when I run PHP Run/Debug configuration in PhpStorm:
File: /home/username/PhpstormProjects/proj/vendor/bin/doctrine-module

it prints:

> docker://image_name/container_name /var/www/vendor/bin/doctrine-module
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 765
>
> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: Service with name "doctrine.connection.orm_default" could not be created. Reason: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 765
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0001     349368   1. {main}() /var/www/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module:0
>       0.0268     360480   2. include('/var/www/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module.php') /var/www/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module:4
>       0.9376    4076096   3. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get() /var/www/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module.php:61
>       0.9376    4076096   4. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate() /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:200
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

I checked that when PDO is creating it receives absolutely the same arguments

`new PDO("mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=dbname", "user", "pass", [])`

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: DockerfileNginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
            - php
        working_dir: /var/www
        links:
            - php
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
        links:
            - db
    php:
        container_name: php
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: DockerfilePhp
            - db
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
        expose:
            - "9000"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        container_name: db
        image: "mysql:5.6"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
            MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
```

Comment: I guess you should use localhost instead of db in the connection string, because PHPStorm is running from outside containers: new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=dbname", "user", "pass", []); That should work as you already mapped "3306:3306" (there's a strange character after that btw)

Comment: PHPStorm executes the tests inside the container. The host "db" is correct.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and I found out, that PHPStorm starts a new, dedicated Docker container for your PHP calls. So, all your docker-compose configuration is missing at this point.

I did the following:

- start your Docker stack with compose
- after that find your network name with `docker network ls` (see [Cannot link to a running container started by docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489696/cannot-link-to-a-running-container-started-by-docker-compose) for help)
- inside PHPStorm goto your preferences for your Docker container (Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit: Docker container ...) and add a link to your db (something like: name = your_containter_name_1, alias = db) and change the network mode from bridge to your network name