# Accessing a running container from a container launched via compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a docker container running on a host that is launched via the standard "docker run ..." command. The network that it's running on is the default name of "directory_default", where "directory" is the name of the current dir.

I've also got a docker compose file (on the same host) that contains another container definition that needs to access the already running container. However, I keep seeing an error when running the compose file stating the network cannot be accessed.

Reading [Cannot link to a running container started by docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489696/cannot-link-to-a-running-container-started-by-docker-compose) seems to point to a similar problem but the other way round (connecting to running containers launched via compose).

I've tried setting env variables in compose and using the --project-name flag to set the network but no luck. I have also tried using the "network" section of the compose file to define the network name I see when running:

```
docker network ls
```

but when running:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

then gives the error:

```
ERROR: Service "my_service" uses an undefined network "my_already_existing_network that you see from docker network ls"
```

Here's the output/files that are being used (running in the directory "test"):

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                  DRIVER              SCOPE
fc4c3de62436        bridge                bridge              local
db6b28f177d0        test_default          bridge              local
5db4787312e5        host                  host                local
64dfb53be850        none                  null                local
```

The first container is started via "docker run ..." as stated earlier from the "test" directory. The compose file is as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:

test_container1:
    networks:
        - test_default 
    image: mytest
    container_name: mytest
    restart: on-failure 
    ports: 
        - "8003:8003"
```

I've also tried removing the "networks" section above and invoking docker-compose with:

```
--project-name test_default
```

as described in the compose docs. I am not using swarm mode.

Comment: Can you pls add compose file, network detail(driver). are you using swarm mode?

Comment: added detail to OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this docker-compose: (you need to specify that the network already exists)

```
version: "3"
services:

  test_container1:
      networks:
          - test_default
      image: mytest
      container_name: mytest
      restart: on-failure
      ports:
          - "8003:8003"

networks:
   test_default:
     external: true
```